# undefined method `defaults' for God::Contacts::Email:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, god

I've installed god using:

```
sudo apt-get install god
```

because after installing the gem god command was still not recognized.
now when i rub god i get:

```
undefined method `defaults' for God::Contacts::Email:Class
```

i am getting the feeling that it installed me an old version of god, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Call me crazy, but did you do this?:

```
$ sudo gem install god
```

I'm unaware of `apt-get` installing gems for you in the right place.

### UPDATE

I'm fairly sure you're going to have to change/add an apt-get repository to get the updated version of god, it looks like this error is from having an older version installed.  However, I'd definitely first try to figure out why this is not working at the gem level.  I think specifically, you want god version 0.11.0

Comment: yes, but after doing that I got: god :command not found, so i search a bit and found the apt-get solution

Comment: @Ran  I found this thread, it may help you out.  Just did a google search http://forum.slicehost.com/comments.php?DiscussionID=3538

Comment: @Ran what version of rails are you using?  Have you tried just doing a `bundle install`?

Comment: I am using rails 2.3.8, What is bundle install?

Comment: @Ran something new introduced in Rails 3, it makes problems like this less frequent, as it installs all of your gems for you.